# How do I use 'expect' to read the contents of a file into a variable?

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

I am having troubles writing an expect script. I want to do something equivalent to the following bash instruction:

```
iplist=$(cat iplist.txt)
```

I've tried using `set` in all the ways that I know but it is still not working.  Is there another way or is just that I'm not using it the right way?

```
set iplist=$(cat iplist.txt)
```

Comment: @don_crissti. Perfect! Sorry about that! I rolled it back ;-)

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCL can [`read(n)`](https://wiki.tcl.tk/1182) a file directly; this is both more efficient and more portable than forking out to some command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

proc slurp {file} {
    set fh [open $file r]
    set ret [read $fh]
    close $fh
    return $ret
}

set iplist [slurp iplist.txt]

puts -nonewline $iplist
```

This also (if necessary) allows various [`open(n)`](https://wiki.tcl.tk/1241) or [`chan configure`](https://wiki.tcl.tk/15111) options to be specified, for example to set the encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

package require Tcl 8.5

proc slurp {file {enc utf-8}} {
    set fh [open $file r]
    chan configure $fh -encoding $enc
    set ret [read $fh]
    close $fh
    return $ret
}

set data [slurp [lindex $argv 0] shiftjis]

chan configure stdout -encoding utf-8
puts $data
```

Which if saved as `readfile` and given `somefile` as input:

```
% file somefile
somefile: DBase 3 data file with memo(s) (1317233283 records)
% xxd somefile
00000000: 8365 8342 8362 834e 838b                 .e.B.b.N..
% ./readfile somefile
ティックル
%
```

Comment: You're leaking file descriptors. You should close the file in the slurp proc.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your answers, I've just found the solution in another post, in the function `set` the only missing was "exec", resulting the line:

```
set iplist [exec cat /root/iplist.txt]
```

---

And the expect file is going well, without any troubles!

Comment: If this is the solution, please mark it as such by clicking the ✔ to the left of this answer to indicate this.  Welcome to U&L!